# getting error when trying to connect to tfs by tee clc

Tags: tfs, team-explorer-everywhere

I installed team explorer everywhere clc and I'm trying via the shell with tf command to connect to our tfs server like that:

```
tf workspace -new Beta1 -collection:http://server:port/tfs/path_to_collection
```

then I get

```
Default credentials are unavailable because no Kerberos ticket or other authentication token is available.
```

it asks for my username and password. After I submit them I'm getting the next response

```
An error occurred: The SOAP endpoint http://server:port/tfs/path_to_collection/Services/v1.0/Registration.asmx could not be contacted.  HTTP status: 404
```

What is the problem exactly?

Comment: What version of TFS are you trying to connect to? What version of TEE did you install?

Comment: I'm using TFS 2015, TEE-CLC 14.134.0

Comment: I found my mistake, I gave the path to a team project instead of the collection